# ASP.NET MVC : how to disable Items of Select List from enum

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I try to disable specific item in select list while the PublishDate date is less than current date.

This is my enum list:

```
public enum Status    
{
    test = 0,
    start = 1,
    end = 2,
    Cancel = 3
}
```

In the controller, I am using this to get the list:

```
private void HandleDropdown(ViewModel model)
{            
    var statusValues = typeof(Status).GetEnumValues().Cast<Status>();

    model.StatusSelect = new List<SelectListItem>();

    foreach (var v in statusValues)
    {
        if (model.PublishDate < DateTime.Now)
        {
            model.StatusSelect.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = EnumHelper.GetDisplayName(v), Value = ((int)v).ToString(), Disabled = true}); // I try to disable in this if statement
        }
        else
        {
            model.StatusSelect.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = EnumHelper.GetDisplayName(v), Value = ((int)v).ToString() });
        }
    }
}
```

I try to disable the status test, start, end (!Cancel) in the if statement. Any way I can do that?

Comment: Are trying to dissable all or some of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it without using helper

if you want to dissable all

```
if (model.PublishDate < DateTime.Now)
model.StatusSelect.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = Enum.GetName(typeof(Status), v), Value = ((int)v).ToString(), Disabled = true}); 
else
model.StatusSelect.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = Enum.GetName(typeof(Status), v), Value = ((int)v).ToString() });
```

if only some of them

```
if ( (model.PublishDate < DateTime.Now ) && ((int)v !=3)) //Cancel will not be disabled
```

Comment: HI, this is great. and totally what i want. but when i implement this i found when try to edit it wont able to save because of it return null. How should i save the original value of it? Thanks, i still fresh for the MVC

Comment: @czroo How are you going to save? Can you post your code pls?